# Pendulum ball hitting a ball at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, projectile

I conducted an experiment and I am using a pendulum to swing a ball from theta back from a line perpendicular to the horizontal see figure 1.

Figure 1
[image]

the mass not attached to the pendulum will be collided with and move in some Velocity at an angle to the horizontal.

Figure 2
[image]

M2 is going to fly off in a direction at a velocity and travel Sx, and depending on how much energy is transfered from M1 to M2, M1 one will either head backwards towards the perpendicular or forwards along its path until its energy depletes and heads back towards the perpendicular.
I cant work out how to show these relationships mathematically.

Any help is greatly apricated. I am a highschool physics student but I am open to 1st or 2nd year university content if its relevant.

Comment: Can you make the experiment simpler by setting $\theta_2=0$?

Comment: Are you assuming that there is no kinetic energy lost during the collision? Usually there will be some loss of kinetic energy given approximately by the [Law of Restitution](https://study.com/academy/lesson/newton-s-law-of-restitution-definition-use.html#:~:text=Newton's%20law%20of%20restitution%20says,from%20which%20they%20are%20made.&text=This%20is%20a%20useful%20measure,or%20elasticity%2C%20of%20the%20collision).

Comment: @sammygerbil unfortunately I cannot cause for the project to be viable m2 must become a projectile with a parabolic path. Also, i will look into the law of restitution, thanks for that

Comment: The path will still be a parabola if $\theta_2=0$. The difficulty I anticipate is that it will be difficult to ensure that $m_1$ is moving exactly towards the centre of $m_2$ when it strikes $m_2$. If it does not then the launch angle for $m_2$ will not be equal to $\theta_2$. However if $m_2$ rolls or slides along the table after the collision then you can be sure that the launch angle is $0$.

Comment: What measurements have you made? What is the purpose of your experiment?

Comment: @sammygerbil I will be using a modified newtons cradle to ensure a repeatable experiment for theta 1. I agree that once m1 strike m2 unless measurements and collisions are exact the path of m2 will become very unpredictable. I am trying to prove that there is a relationship between the changing theta 1 and the horizontal displacement of m2

Comment: So $\theta_2$ is not a variable? Then you could set $\theta_2=0$? That would make your calculations easier. Calculate the velocity $v_1$ of $m_1$ just before the collision, using conservation of energy (ie loss of gravitational PE = gain of KE). If the balls are steel then usually the coefficient of restitution is $e=1$. (This is the same as assuming no loss of kinetic energy during the collision.) Use $e=1$ and conservation of momentum to calculate velocity $v_2$. From the height $y$ you can calculate the time of flight $t$ using $y=\frac12 g t^2$. Then the horizontal range is $x=v_2 t$.

Comment: @sammygerbil I spoke to my partner and he agrees with you, we have made theta 2 approximately 0, (there is still some angle but we are assuming that it is too minimal to have a notable impact) Thanks for all your help mate